# Fast way of counting number of occurrences of a word in a string using Java

Tags: java, regex, find-occurrences

I want to find number of times a word appears in a string in a fast and efficient way using Java.

The words are separated by space and I am looking for complete words.

```
Example: 
string: "the colored port should be black or white or brown"
word: "or"
output: 2
```

for the above example, "colored" and "port" are not counted, but "or" is counted.

I considered using **substring()** and **contains()** and iterating over the string. But then we need to check for the surrounding spaces which I suppose is not efficient. Also **StringUtils.countMatches()** is not efficient.

The best way I tried is splitting the string over space and iterating over the words, and then matching them against the given *word*:

```
String string = "the colored port should be black or white or brown";
String[] words = string.split(" ");
String word = "or";
int occurrences = 0;
for (int i=0; i<words.length; i++)
    if (words[i].equals(word))
        occurrences++;
System.out.println(occurrences);
```

But I am expecting some efficient way using **Matcher** and **regex**.

So I tested the following code:

```
        String string1 = "the colored port should be black or white or brown or";
        //String string2 = "the color port should be black or white or brown or";
        String word = "or";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s(" + word + ")|\\s(" + word + ")|(" + word + ")\\s");
        Matcher  matcher = pattern.matcher(string1);
        //Matcher  matcher = pattern.matcher(string2);
        int count = 0;
        while (matcher.find()){
            match=matcher.group();
            count++;
        }
        System.out.println("The word \"" + word + "\" is mentioned " + count + " times.");
```

It is supposed to be fast enough, and gives me the right answer for string1, but not for string2 (commented). There seems to need a little change in the regex.

Any ideas?

Comment: what did you find when you searched for "java fast string matching"  or "java fast word counting"?

Comment: `int output = Collections.frequency(Arrays.asList(string.split(" ")), word);`

Comment: @MitchWheat I found some substring based solutions as I mentioned some of them above. But the problem is that there are huge number of strings and words to search, and I am looking for a more efficient solution, probably based on "Matcher".

Comment: `"the colored port should be black or white or brown".split(" or ").length-1);`?

Comment: Thanks @Baby but this won't work for the first and last words.

Comment: Are there going to be a bunch of words you need to match on?

Comment: Yes. Lots of them. The above sample block I wrote will be inside two loops; one for different strings and another for different words.

Comment: I just started learning about streams.  Have you thought about if parallelStream would work well in this case?

Comment: You could use Baby's solution, after appending a space to the beginning and end

Comment: If you have a lot of searches, split the sentence into words and put them with a count in a HashMap<String,Imteger>, then use the get() method.

Comment: @qxz that's a cute fix, and works perfectly. But there would be another efficiency problem based on my previous experience; string manipulations (appending space to two sides of another string, and then splitting it) for huge strings tends to be slow.

Comment: So you're not reading the text from a file?

Comment: Have you seen efficiency problems using 4castle's solution using `Collections.frequency()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I experimented and evaluated three answers; **split based** and **Matcher based** (as mentioned in the question), and **Collections.frequency()** based (as mentioned in a comment above by @4castle). Each time I measured the total time in a loop repeated 10 million times. As a result, the **split** based answer tends to be the *most efficient way*:

```
String string = "the colored port should be black or white or brown";
String[] words = string.split(" ");
String word = "or";
int occurrences = 0;
for (int i=0; i<words.length; i++)
    if (words[i].equals(word))
        occurrences++;
System.out.println(occurrences);
```

Then there is **Collections.frequency()** based answer with a little longer running time (~5% slower):

```
String string = "the colored port should be black or white or brown or";
String word = "or";
int count = Collections.frequency(Arrays.asList(string.split(" ")), word);
System.out.println("The word \"" + word + "\" is mentioned " + count + " times.");
```

The **Matcher based** solution (mentioned in the question) is a lot slower (~5 times more running time).

Answer (score 0):

How about this? Assuming `word` wont have spaces.

```
string.split("\\s"+word+"\\s").length - 1;
```

Comment: @NickZiebert, post your separate query, as of now OP needs just one word to search

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str= "the colored port should be black or white or brown";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(" or ");
    Matcher  matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

    int count = 0;
    while (matcher.find())
        count++;

    System.out.println(count);    
}
```

}